# How to call the second mehtod in "takeUntilDestroyed" in a angular app with angular 17

Tags: angular

I change all my code to angular 17 with new feature. the question is, in some code,

in the ngOnDestroy mehtod, it contains not only the .next() and complete() call, but also calling the other mehtod.

```
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
    this.test.clearSelectedCases();
  }
```

and now I have changed or used:

```
 private destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);
```

and in the subscribe mehtod

such as

```
 test.pipe(
        takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef)
      ).subscribe(...)
```

in this case how can I call the method this.test.clearSelectedCases();

any solutison?

Answer (score 2):

```
test.pipe(
    takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef),
    finalize(() => { this.test.clearSelectedCases(); })
  ).subscribe(...)
```